# SQL Server large join query with duplicate columns can't be exported

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, prefix

I'm dealing with a large SQL query involving many joins (using T-SQL) with tables whose columns are no longer unique with the join.  The result has >600 columns.  Is there a way to prefix the result columns with their table name without calling out every column explicitly in the select portion of the query so that I can export this to CSV with unique column names?

For example, we have 28 tables, some of which share a common column name.  I cannot export this to csv because it has no way of knowing the difference between the columns with similar names.

```
       TABLE 1
| columnA | columnB |

       TABLE 2
| columnC | columnB |
```

result looks like:

```
| columnA | columnB | columnC | columnB |
```

I can't export the result set because `columnB` is used twice as a column name.

I'd like the result set to read:

```
| TABLE1.columnA | TABLE1.columnB | TABLE2.columnC | TABLE2.columnB |
```

Comment: You mean like using an alias? `SELECT T1.COLUMNNAME, T2.COLUMNNAME FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID;`?

Comment: Yes I do.  But I'd like to avoid having to type out an alias for each of the 618 columns manually

Comment: So, `SELECT *`? Can you try to explain more here, please?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't prefix the columns in the result set...

Comment: Expand your question and show what you're looking for. This is unclear.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for your patience and willingness to look into this.  Let me know if I can clarify anything else!

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can really do this is using Dynamic SQL or typing them all out. As you don't want to do the latter, that leaves you with the former. Note that the below is a sample, you'll need to amend the below for your own needs, however, it should get you on the right path.

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE Customer (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                       [Name] varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE Item (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                   [Name] varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE CustomerOrder (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                            ItemID int,
                            CustomerID int);
GO
INSERT INTO Customer ([Name])
VALUES ('Joe Bloggs'),('Jayne Smith');
INSERT INTO Item ([Name])
VALUES ('Spanner'),('Saw'),('Screwdriver');
INSERT INTO CustomerOrder (ItemID, CustomerID)
VALUES (1,1),(3,1),(3,1),(2,2),(3,2);
GO
SELECT *
FROM Customer C
     JOIN CustomerOrder CO ON C.ID = CO.CustomerID
     JOIN Item I ON CO.ItemID = I.ID;
GO
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' +
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(10) + N'       ' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N' AS ' + QUOTENAME(t.[name] + N'.' + c.[name])
                  FROM sys.columns c
                       JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
                  WHERE t.[name] IN (N'Customer',N'Item',N'CustomerOrder')
                  FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,9,N'') + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM Customer' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'     JOIN CustomerOrder ON Customer.ID = CustomerOrder.CustomerID' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'     JOIN Item ON CustomerOrder.ItemID = Item.ID;';

PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
--SELECT @SQL; --your other best friend, as I'd guess @SQL is actually going to have more than 4000 characters and PRINT can't handle that

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

GO
DROP TABLE Customer;
DROP TABLE Item;
DROP TABLE CustomerOrder;
GO
```

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I can.  Thanks for your time!